# How can I access JavaScript function argument outside the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I access the function arguments outside the function?

Here is my code:

```
function viewmessage(username,name) {
        //alert(name + " : " + username);
        $('#heading').html(name);
        $.get('/notification/viewmessage', {user:username}, function(data) {
            $('#messagesfrom').html(data);
            $('#newmessage').slideDown(200);
        });
    }
alert(name + " : " + username);
```

Comment: There is no *nice* way to do it, because it shouldn't be done.

Comment: Not sure exactly what your question is here.  Javascript is like most languages, you can't access variables outside their scope.  What is it that you are trying to do (more code may help).

Comment: That is not possible no. In the meantime, those parameters must come from somewhere right ? How do you call this function ? Why do you want to alert outside the function ?

Comment: What is your primary motivation to do it? The alert line in your example could be easily done inside the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, unless you declare the variable outside the function.

You can only use the same variable names in the global scope:

```
function viewmessage(username, name){
    window.username = username;
    window.name = name;
}
alert(window.name + " : " + window.username ); // "undefined : undefined"
alert(name+" : "+username); // ReferenceError: 'name' not defined
```

In a local scope, you have to use variable names which are re-declared inside the function:

```
var username2, name2;
function viewmessage(username, name){
    username2 = username; // No "var"!!
    name2 = name;
}
alert(username2 + " : " + name2); // "undefined : undefined"
viewmessage('test', 'test2');
alert(username2 + " : " + name2); // "test : test2"
```

Comment: @NickyDeMaeyer You're referring to the use of global variables. That's not recommended, because of potential variable conflicts with other embedded scripts. Also, the global scope should not unnecessarily be polluted with unnecessary global variables.

Answer (score 6):

You can use RegEx (regular expressions) to get the arguments:

```
function viewmessage(username, name) {/*...*/}
var args = viewmessage.toSource()
           .match(/\((?:.+(?=\s*\))|)/)[0]
           .slice(1).split(/\s*,\s*/g);
//args = ["username", "name"]
```

Make sure though, you don't have any spaces after the `(` or before the `)`. Otherwise, you might have this result:

```
function viewmessage( username, name ) {/*...*/}
var args = viewmessage.toSource()
           .match(/\((?:.+(?=\s*\))|)/)[0]
           .slice(1).split(/\s*,\s*/g);
//args = [" username", "name "]
```

Or you use `trim()` on each of the arguments after you gathered them:

```
args.forEach(function (e, i, a) {a[i] = e.trim();});
//args = ["username", "name"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return those variables in the function:

```
var viewmessage = function(username, name){
    // Blabla
    return {
        username: username,
        name: name
    }
}

// And then...
var vm = viewmessage('wutup', 'Peter');
alert(vm.name +" : "+ vm.username);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the function me put an the username as id for a submit button.  or can use an empty div too.

```
function viewmessage(username,name){
        //alert(name+" : "+username);
        $("#submit").attr('id', username);
        $('#heading').html(name);
        touser = username;
        $.get('/notification/viewmessage',{user:username},function(data){
            $('#messagesfrom').html(data);
            $('#newmessage').slideDown(200);
        });
    }
var touser = $("#submit").attr("id");
alert(touser);
```

thanks to those who answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't access the function's parameters from outside the function. That is what variable scoping is all about.

If what you want is to access the variable's value, you need to pass that value to a global variable from inside your function, and then you'll be able to access that value from outside.

Do not confuse the variable with the value.

Answer (score 0):

This relates to the scoping of arguments and where they are defined.  You need to wrap the alert in a function that receives the arguments.  Either a function that calls viewMessage and then alert, or if you want the alert after the ajax request move the alert into the success handler, as shown:

```
function viewmessage(username,name){
        $('#heading').html(name);
        $.get('/notification/viewmessage',{user:username},function(data){
            $('#messagesfrom').html(data);
            $('#newmessage').slideDown(200);
            alert(name+" : "+username);
        });
    }
```