# retrieve parameters of a jsFunction listed into a nodeList

Tags: javascript, nodelist

I'm trying to retrieve the parameters of a onclick attribute into a webpage.
So far i've been able to retrieve the function with all the parameters using nodeValue listing.
But once there i'm wondering how to get some parameters of the function.
This code:

```
var action = document.getElementById('action_3')
for (var att, i = 0, atts = action.attributes, n = atts.length, arr = []; i < n; i++){
 att = atts[i];
console.log(atts.onclick.nodeValue);
}
```

gets me this result

```
cba.facture.controllers.factureListeController.createFactureListeTooltipActionDialog('73928462',
                         'action_3_TooltipDialog',
                         'action_3',
                         '190px', 'Télétransmise', '1', 'false', '0',
                         '7622', '14962', 'Télétransmise', '')
```

Now i'm trying to retrieve the parameters of the createFactureListeTooltipActionDialog, but i don't really know how..

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39438293/65232

Comment: ok, thanks . I'll work on this